# Can someone help me understand this SMPS circuit with the UC3843 feedback configured in this particular way?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, feedback

Can someone help me understand what the behavior of the SMPS is with the UC3843 feedback configured in this particular way? And, how does this UC3843 feedback configured in this particular way bring about this behavior in the SMPS?
[image]

Comment: Looks like the standard configuration for a simple flyback switcher with the exception I’ve not seen one drawn in such an unconventional manner. Have you referred to the UC3843 datasheet and app notes? There should be some discussion regarding the TL431 and associated components.

Comment: Where did you find this circuit?

Comment: @TimWilliams This is a schematic my supervisor gave me at a place I'm doing an internship at.

Comment: @Kartman No I haven't, thanks for bring that to my attention.

Comment: Well, looking at the absence of feedback network across the TL431, I would not power this up. Furthermore, a 100-µH inductor with a 1-mF output capacitor, same comment: this circuit has probably never been built.

Comment: @VerbalKint The circuit has been built and tested and it works, or at least that's what I was told; I haven't seen it running with my own eyes. Btw, this circuit is for charging a SLA battery.

Comment: Ok, I assume it is supposed to be a constant-voltage constant-current charger (CV-CC) but a) there is no current loop per se, U7's LED will be activated when the ohmic drop reaches 1 V or so - I let you imagine how precise and "lazy" it can be and b) a compensation network should be placed from the REF to the CATHODE of the TL431, not across it which is absolutely unusual. Please a look at this [seminar](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/The%20TL431%20in%20Switching%20Power%20Supplies.pdf) where you will see how to properly wire a TL431 in a regulation loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to be a fairly standard way of getting both a 24 volt regulated output with the added bonus of over-current-limiting: -

[image]

U5 (the TL431) starts shunting current from pin 3 to pin 2 when the gate (pin 1) reaches about 2.5 volts. This will start to activate opto U6.

Looking at R11, R13 and R13 (forming a potential divider); it's about right in that with 24 volts on Vout, the TL431's gate will be at around 2.5 volts.

This is as conventional as it gets with a lot of Flyback converters.

The other opto-isolator (U7) starts to activate when the voltage across the current sense resistor (R10) is sufficient: -

[image]

Use of the comp pin on the UC3843 for the feedback point is pretty normal too.

Regarding the schematic, it's badly segregated into almost pointless sub-sections that make it hard to decipher. Having said that, the simplicity of the basic circuit means it took me 5 minutes instead of 2 minutes.

> *Also, can you also explain the role of ISENSE in the feedback
> mechanism of this circuit?*

**ISENSE** is an input to the UC3843. It monitors the current that passes through the switching MOSFET Q1 using R2. When the MOSFET activates, the current into the transformer primary ramps up to a certain value and, the MOSFET then deactivates. **ISENSE** is used to deactivate the MOSFET. This is set by the value of resistor R2. So, if the voltage across R2 exceeds 1 volt (as stated in the data sheet), the MOSFET is deactivated.

Comment: So what I understand is that when the output voltage tries to go above 24V, the UC3843 reduces the duty cycle of Q1 to keep the output regulated at 24V (depending on the exact setting of R13). And, it also ensures that the current doesn't exceed a certain limit through the same process. Is my understanding correct?
Also, can you also explain the role of ISENSE in the feedback mechanism of this circuit?

Comment: @xrosaber yes your understanding is correct and, I've added a section to my answer regarding the ISENSE pin.

Comment: Oh okay, so the purpose of the ISENSE pin is ensure the current through the transformer does not exceed 8A, right?

Comment: Yes, 8 amps @xrosaber